# Form: onsubmit not taking return value from a function

Tags: javascript, forms, handlebars.js

I am currently a beginner in webdevlopment sector(and also new in stackoverflow..srry in advance for poor question format).Basically, i am having issues with the onsubmit event which is not taking the return value from the function which is being called....the function is:

```
  function checkUnique1() {
var ok = true;
socket.emit('eCheck', {email: document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value});
socket.on('eValidateMessage', function(obj) {
  if(obj.message == false)
  {

    document.getElementsByName("email")[0].style.borderColor = "#E34234";
    document.getElementById("emailExist").innerHTML = "Email has not been registered";
    document.getElementById("emailExist").style.color = "#E34234";
    ok = false;
  }
});


return ok;}
```

I am using this function to check if email is present in database or not..if it is present the function should return true and onsubmit should fire else it will return false and onsubmit wont fire and the form wont be submitted....here is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/forgotPass" onsubmit="return checkUnique1()"  method="post" id="formid">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4"><h1>Creators Space</h1></label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2"></label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
      <label class="control-label">Please enter the email registered with Creators Space</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" onclick="emailRSet()" onkeypress="emailRSet()" placeholder="Enter email" required title="email (format: xx@xx.xx/xx@xx.xx.xx)" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
    <span id="emailExist"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

now this works good in when all the above code is in an html file but when I do the same thing in handlebars template the function doesnt seem to return any value so form is being submitted in both cases.
**How can I do the same in an handlebars template???What could be the problem??**

Please let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function on `socket.on(function)` probably executes asynchronously (that is, not right away, but some time in the future), so when that `return ok` executes, the function on `socket.on(function)` has not been executed yet, thus `ok` still has value of `true`.

Maybe something like the below would work:

```
function checkUnique1() {
    // make sure only the submit button of that form matches this selector
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("form.form-horizontal button[value='submit']");
    var typedEmail = document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value;

    // disable the submit button upon click to prevent multiple submits
    submitButton.disabled = true;

    if (window.validatedEmail === typedEmail) {
       // email has been validated, submit form
       return true;
    } else {
      // email has not been validated, request validation
      socket.emit('eCheck', {email: document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value});
      socket.on('eValidateMessage', function(obj) {
        if(obj.message == false)
        {
          document.getElementsByName("email")[0].style.borderColor = "#E34234";
          document.getElementById("emailExist").innerHTML = "Email has not been registered";
          document.getElementById("emailExist").style.color = "#E34234";

          // re-enables the submit button, since the email was not validated
          submitButton.disabled = false;
          // clears validatedEmail (since validation failed, no email has been validated)
          window.validatedEmail = null;
        }
        else {
          // 'marks' the typed e-mail as validated
          window.validatedEmail = typedEmail;

          // make sure only that form matches this selector
          document.querySelector("form.form-horizontal").submit();
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
}
```

The code above creates a global variable `window.validatedEmail` with the last email that has been validated.

Link with a demo fiddle for debugging: **https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/3v52u69u/2/** (it has some changes from the answer, since I didn't have access to your websocket, I used a different one, so I had to make some adaptations).

## Code breakdown

Per comment:

> `if (window.validatedEmail === typedEmail)` part..like what is `window.validatedEmail` doing and why are you checking if it is equal to `typedEmail`?

When the form submits, the code checks if there is a (global) variable `window.validatedEmail` and, if there is, if it is equal to the typed email (`typedEmail`).

When the form is first submitted, that `if` will be `false`, since there will be no `window.validatedEmail`. Now, when that `if` is `false` we go to the `else` part. The `else` part just makes a validation request to the websocket (`socket.emit`) and registers a listener function (`socket.on('eValidateMessage', function(obj) { ... }`) that will be executed when the validation responds.

When the validation responds and `function(obj) { ... }` is executed, it does the following: if the validation message tells us that the email was not validated (that is, `obj.message == false`), then it adds the error messages and enables the submit button back, so the user can press it again after she changes the email.

Now, on the other hand, if the validation message tells us that the email **was** validated (which is the `else` part of the `if` inside `function(obj) { ... }`), then we save the `typedEmail` (which we know has just been validated) in the global variable `window.validatedEmail` and re-submit the form.

This time, when the form is re-submitted, it will, as usual, first check if the global variable `window.validatedEmail` exists and if it is equal to `typedEmail`. What is different now is that `window.validatedEmail` do will exist -- because we have saved it in the `else` part of the `function(obj) { ... }`.

And since it exists and is equal to `typedEmail`, then we simply `return true`, which will allow the form to be submitted.

Comment: the onclick="this.disabled = true" is stopping the form from submitting at all and without it the form is still submitting on both cases.. on another note you said socket.on() is executing asynchronously, so is there a way to make   the rest of the function wait for the execution of return of in my code..thnks in advance

Comment: About the button stopping the form from submitting, I updated the code. No need to have those changes to the HTML. Check the updated answer. Also, about the socket, I don't believe you have a way to execute it synchronously, so, no, there wouldn't be a way to make the rest of the function wait for that execution, unfortunately.

Comment: In your code I am not getting desired border color and innerhtml value if the email is not in the database

Comment: Sure, the code assumed a given global variable was defined, which was not always the case. I updated the code. Can you check it now?

Comment: Thnks a lot ...it worked for both the cases...but I am having trouble understanding it can you please explain what are you doing in this code and why it worked cause that would we great :-)

Comment: Which part, specifically, you don't understand?

Comment: if (window.validatedEmail === typedEmail) part..like what is  window.validatedEmail doing and why are you checking if  it is equal to typedEmail

Comment: I added the explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thnks a lot ...that cleared so much I would upvote your answer but the site says i have less than 15 reputation so I cant

Comment: Hah, no worries. Glad it helped.